# Does ASP.NET Core 7 with minimal api's allow for 500 errors to be sent as problem details?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-7.0

For an ASP.NET Core 7 "Minimal Api" web app, can 500 server error responses be formatted as problem details?

Is this automatic? What about stack traces - can the `Environment.IsDevelopment()` be used to set/not-set the stack trace in the JSON response (where env is Dev)?

Comment: Are you asking if you can include a stack trace with any 500 error sent back to the client? Probably, but it's generally considered a security issue if you send specifics about your application internals to the general public. That's why 500 errors in production usually need to be investigated in private back end logs

Comment: I am asking 2 things -> how can I define any 500 server error as a problem-detail response and if this is possible, how to only include the stack trace if it is Env.IsDev()

Answer (score 1):

> For an ASP.NET Core 7 "Minimal Api" web app, can 500 server error
> responses be formatted as problem details?

Yes, it can, If you use [problem details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0&preserve-view=true#problem-details) extentison method, it will bind the responses for all HTTP client and server errors which doesn't have the body content. So, you can bind your 500 internal error but you cannot return as response body. You can do as following:

```
app.MapGet("/test", (HttpContext context) =>
{
    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
    context.Response.ContentType = Text.Plain;

    var title = "Any Title";
    var detail = "Error detils";
    var type = "Type of error";
    var status = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;

    if (status.ToString() == "500")
    {
        if (context.RequestServices.GetService<IProblemDetailsService>() is
            { } problemDetailsService)
        {
            var exceptionHandlerFeature =
           context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();

            problemDetailsService.WriteAsync(new ProblemDetailsContext
            {
                HttpContext = context,
                ProblemDetails =
                {
                    Title = title,
                    Detail = detail,
                    Type = type,
                    Status = status
                }
            });
        }

       
    }

    return Results.Ok();

});
```

**Note:** Microsoft doesn't recommned to expose error details other than development environment due to the security risk.

[image]

> Is this automatic?

Yes, its automatic, but still you can  customize the response by using [CustomizeProblemDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0&preserve-view=true#customize-problem-details) and your modification can be applied to all auto-generated problem details. You can do as following:

```
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails(options =>
    options.CustomizeProblemDetails = ctx =>
            ctx.ProblemDetails.Extensions.Add("nodeId", Environment.MachineName));
```

In addition, `ProblemDetails.Extensions` is a `IDictionary` type which contains `IDictionary<string, object?>`, so any additional information can be passed here.

[image]

**Note:** If your need more detials, please [refer to this official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0&preserve-view=true#produce-a-problemdetails-payload-for-exceptions)

Comment: Hi! I don't understand 2x things. 1) Why did you manually create a problem details in the test endpoint? I thought your test endpoint would just throw an exception and then the problem details middleware (is it a middleware?) will do all the magic? 2) How can you customize the ProblemDetails to not show any stack trace? In your example above, you're only adding a nodeId.

Comment: Alright, I just did it to test on my side and it will be thrown automatically by the `AddProblemDetails` extension method. No sir, that's an extension method. Well, regarding `Extensions.Add` is a dictionary type so you can include all of your necessary information like stacktrace or any additional information and `nodeId`  is a key  you can pass object containing your required informtion into it. Based on your comment, I have already upated the answer, please have a look.